# How to replace synchronized, wait, notify by semaphores? (Producer-Consumer)

Tags: java, wait, semaphore, synchronized, notify

Good evening,

I am wondering how I can replace synchronized, wait and notify in the following code by semaphores? And where do I have to create the semaphore variable?

```
   import java.util.*;

   class Producer
   extends Thread
   {
     private Vector v;

     public Producer(Vector v)
     {
       this.v = v;
     }

     public void run()
     {
       String s;

       while (true) {
         synchronized (v) {
           s = "Value"+Math.random();
           v.addElement(s);
           System.out.println("Producer created "+s);
           v.notify();
         }
         try {
           Thread.sleep((int)(100*Math.random()));
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           //nothing
         }
       }
     }
   }

   class Consumer
   extends Thread
   {
      private Vector v;

      public Consumer(Vector v)
      {
         this.v = v;
      }

      public void run()
      {
         while (true) {
            synchronized (v) {
               if (v.size() < 1) {
                  try {
                     v.wait();
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     //nothing
                  }
               }
               System.out.print(
                 " Consumer found "+(String)v.elementAt(0)
               );
               v.removeElementAt(0);
               System.out.println(" (remaning: "+v.size()+")");
            }
            try {
               Thread.sleep((int)(100*Math.random()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               //nothing
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me out!

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a semaphore as a lock that can allow multiple threads to access a shared resource. Whatever number you initialize the semaphore to will allow that many threads to access the resource simultaneously. In Producer-Consumer, the resource is a shared buffer between the two threads. You want to make sure that the consumer cannot access the buffer unless it is full, and the producer cannot access the buffer unless it is empty. You should start with a count of 0 in the consumer's semaphore and 1 in the producer's semaphore.That way the Producer has to make the first move. When the Producer begins to write to the buffer, you want to `down` the Producer semaphore. When the Producer is done, you want to `up` the Consumer's semaphore which will allow the Consumer to access the resource. When the consumer has accessed the resource, it then `up`s the producer's semaphore notifying the producer that the buffer is now empty.

Use this as a starting point: http://cs.gmu.edu/cne/modules/ipc/aqua/producer.html

Comment: Hey nLee,.. today I asked a teacher to explain me that everything in detail and he explained me as you did... I want to thank you very much for your answer. You and stackdev have helped me a lot.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
        new Producer(vector, mutex).start();
        new Consumer(vector, mutex).start();
    }
}

class Producer extends Thread {
    private Vector v;
    private Semaphore mutex;

    public Producer(Vector v, Semaphore mutex) {
        this.v = v;
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        String s;

        while (true) {
            try {
                mutex.acquire();
                s = "Value" + Math.random();
                v.addElement(s);
                System.out.println("Producer created " + s);
                mutex.release();
                Thread.sleep((int) (100 * Math.random()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}


class Consumer extends Thread {
    private Vector v;
    private Semaphore mutex;

    public Consumer(Vector v, Semaphore mutex) {
        this.v = v;
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                mutex.acquire();
                if (v.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.print(" Consumer found " + (String) v.elementAt(0));
                    v.removeElementAt(0);
                    System.out.println(" (remaning: " + v.size() + ")");
                }
                mutex.release();
                Thread.sleep((int) (100 * Math.random()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```